# Has anyone built a piano based on the chromatic scale?

Tags: piano

It's a very simple idea although it's difficult to explain exactly what I mean... If you notice for a moment that there are just two sets of whole note scales, if you imagine a piano where all the white keys are one of those whole note scales and all the black keys is the other... so there is no space without black keys like E-F and B-C... Does anyone know if someone has ever built a piano like this? It seems like it would be interesting.

Comment: Short answer: sort of. Long answer: read the answers to the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

While not a piano (but still known as a Stomach Steinway), the are chromatic layouts for button accordions.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_button_accordion